# Change default ReadmeName in Apache

Tags: apache-2.2, directoryindex

How do I change the default ReadmeName for Apache directory indexes?

I have a readme file in the root of my site example.com/README.html which I want to display as the readme file for Apache directory indexes **unless** the directory has it's own README.html file. Is this possible?

Example;
With the directory structure

```
-/
-/folder1/
-/folder1/README.html
-/folder2/
-/README.html
```

example.com/ should display example.com/README.html in it's directory index,
example.com/folder1/ should display example.com/folder1/README.html,
example.com/folder2/ should display example.com/README.html

I can set

```
ReadmeName README.html
```

in my config, but that will display "Apache Server at example.com Port 80" in the footer of the directory index for example.com/folder2/
Likewise I can set

```
ReadmeName /README.html
```

but that will ignore the README.html in folder1/

Did any of that make sense? I'm not doing very well to explain this =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this globally. You can though specify a ReadmeName in the vhost/server context which points to a server wide file e.g.

```
<VirtualHost *80>
    .
    .
    ReadmeName    /README.html
<Virtualhost>
```

This can be overridden per directory with a .htaccess file

```
ReadmeName README.html
```

From the Documentation

> Both HeaderName and ReadmeName now treat Filename as a URI path
>   relative to the one used to access the directory being indexed. If
>   Filename begins with a slash, it will be taken to be relative to the
>   DocumentRoot.

This works on an Ubuntu system I have to hand.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't work for what I'm trying to do. I'm setting up a software mirror server for a few projects, quite a few folders have README.html files in, but not all of them so I wanted to set a 'default' ReadmeName to show up in those.

Comment: I just used different names in my example because I could. Set the server context to `/README.html` and the directory context to `README.html` that should do what you want. You still have to create the .htaccess files but that should be an easy script.

Comment: Yeah I got that, but there are a lot of subdirectories (I'd guess hundreds, maybe thousands) to check, and I have to RSYNC with the delete option so I'd have to re-create them every time. Yes it's possible but I was hoping for an easyer solution

Comment: Also some of the directories have their own .htaccess files to set descriptions and non-standard ReadmeName's (I.E. for an entire directory and it's sub-directories) etc. so I'd have to check for that then append the ReadmeName on the end if needed. Not impossible but annoying

Comment: I hope someone can show us both an easier solution.